# Search resets NSArrayController selection to none

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nssearchfield

I've got an `NSTableView` bound to an `NSArrayController` via `content` and `selection indexes`. All great so far - content displayed, etc.

[image]

Now an `NSSearchField` is bound to the array controller via `filterPredicate` and the property of the array content instances that's to be searched.
Searching/filtering the table view works great; table view showing only matching entries.

**However**, searching resets the selection on the `NSTableView` if the existing selection isn't in the search results. Worse, not only during the search but after ending the search there's no selection on the table view.

The `NSArrayController` is set up to *Avoid Empty Selection*.

Yet, debugging the array controller's `selection indexes` shows that **searching resets them to an empty set.** Don't quite know what to make of it..

Any hints on how to properly configure bindings in this scenario to **really** prevent an empty selection much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately array controllers don't track and restore the selection as their arranged objects change.  You'll have to do this yourself in code.  You can keep track of the current selection by using  KVO to observe the selection on the array controller.  You can also observe the controller's arranged objects to know when it changes as a result of filtering. Upon every change just set the current selection back to the tracked value (assuming its still in arranged objects) or set the selection to a new value.

Comment: uh - seriously? That's pretty disappointing!   
Anywho, thanks for the hint I'll try that approach.

Comment: Let me clarify a little.  The array controller *will* maintain its selection if the selected objects remains in the arranged objects during filtering if the 'Preserves Selection' option is checked for the array controller.  The documentation is a little unclear here.  In the documentation the preserves selection option controls whether the controller remembers its selection when its *content* changes. In this case, we are filtering the existing content not changing it; but nevertheless, it appears that the preserves selection option also applies in this case as well.

Comment: My disappointment was actually referring to **`setAvoidsEmptySelection`** - the docs state that *"If YES, the receiver maintains a selection unless there are no objects in the content array."*. However, when filtering with the predicate the selection can actually become empty when there's still elements in the content array..

Comment: The documentation seems to refer only to the case where the content to the array controller actually changes, e.g. master detail setup.  Here the content does not change only the arranged objects due to filtering.